# Visual Studio keeps generating multiple Strings#.Designer.cs files for Strings.resx

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I have a Strings.resx file in my windows phone 7 mango project (using the latest RC tools for mango). This file contains localized strings for my application. However, it seems every time I make a change and save it, Visual studio adds a NEW Strings1.Designer.cs, Strings2.Designer.cs, etc... each time the file is saved. The original Strings.Designer.cs is no longer updated, so I keep getting Ambiguity errors. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: If you are using any source control (TFS/VSS), is your Designer.cs file checked out? Sometimes I get these duplicates when I have a dependent file not checked out and the IDE would silently create a duplicate and start using it.

Comment: Looks like it might have been Windows Live Mesh interfering with visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just Windows Live Mesh interfering.

Answer (score 2):

I also found that in Visual Studio 2013 (possibly earlier as well) that the **Strings#.designer.cs** name is being saved in the **.csproj** file.  So even once the file system issue is cleared up, VS continues to use Strings# for the filename.

Here are some additional details:
[Why is the generated class for a resource file in a file with a different name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408370/why-is-the-generated-class-for-a-resource-file-in-a-file-with-a-different-name/29053197#29053197)

Comment: This happened to me in VS2015 as well.  I'm not what caused it to happen initially, but manual editing of csproj to correct the "LastGenOutput" node of an embedded resource fixed the problem.