# Why is the generated class for a resource file in a file with a different name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, embedded-resource

I have a resource file strings.resx, and the generated resource class is in strings1.designer.cs. Why is this the case? The problem specifically is the "1". The class name inside that file is "strings", as it should be.

[image: screenshot]

Note that I did try deleting the designer.cs and regenerating it by saving the resx file, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Show hidden files in Solution Explorer. Or open the folder location in explorer.  Do you see the old resx files in there?

Comment: No hidden files in that directory. I inherited this project, and I think they maybe had a bunch of resource files before, causing the number increment. But since those files no longer exist, this shouldn't happen anymore.

Comment: That happened to me one time across development branches.  I never figured out why.  I ended manually renaming the class.  I think I left the file names as they were.

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into this problem and found the issue inside the .csproj file.  It appears that Visual Studio saves the last filename it used and attempts to generate using that filename again.  So if for some reason the **Strings.designer.cs** is ever generated as **Strings1.designer.cs** it looks like VS will continue to use Strings1.

Below you can see the portions of the .csproj file that was giving me an issue.  Most importantly the `<LastGenOutput>` at the end where **Strings1.designer.cs** is saved.

```
<Compile Include="App_GlobalResources\Strings.Designer.cs">
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <DependentUpon>Strings.resx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="App_GlobalResources\Strings.es.designer.cs">
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <DependentUpon>Strings.es.resx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
...
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="App_GlobalResources\Strings.es.resx">
    <Generator>GlobalResourceProxyGenerator</Generator>
    <LastGenOutput>Strings.es.designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
  </EmbeddedResource>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="App_GlobalResources\Strings.resx">
    <Generator>GlobalResourceProxyGenerator</Generator>
    <LastGenOutput>Strings1.designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```

Changing the `<LastGenOutput>` to the following solved my problem:

`<LastGenOutput>Strings.designer.cs</LastGenOutput>`

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Do you know if there is a way to get rid of the Strings.designer.cs file and make it to be autogenerated with every rebuilt?